# How to use JavaScript substring to detect if iFrame source contains a youtube URL?

Tags: javascript, url, youtube

I am trying to detect all iframes on the page that contain a http://www.youtube.com URL, this is what I've got so far:

```
    var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

    for (var i = 0; i != iframes.length; ++i) {
        if(iframes[i].src.substr(0,22) != 'http://www.youtube.com' {
            alert('YouTube video exists');
        }
    }
```

It doens't work, so I don't know what I am doing or if I am using it correctly, any help much appreciated. I then want to run a function for each youtube video embedded. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    var key = /http:\/\/www.youtube.com/;

    for (var i = 0; i != iframes.length; ++i) {
       var match = iframes[i].src.search(key);
       if(match != -1) {
          alert('YouTube video exists');
       }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(iframes[i].src.substr(0,22) === 'http://www.youtube.com')
```

instead of !=